# How can I validate input so that it must be an integer

Tags: validation, python-3.x, integer

I'm trying to validate the input so that it has to be an integer. I have validated the input so that it has to be within a certain range but if they enter the letter 'b' for example, an error appears read "ValueError:invalid literl for int() with base 10". I want the same message in the else section to appear if the value is not an integer. I have been searching the net for a while and cannot figure out how to validate the input so it must be an integer.

```
Minutes=int(input("How long do you want the interval between each stretch to be?\nIndicate a number in minutes between 5 and 60\n\nAfter the minutes specified, a window with suggested stretches will appear\n--> "))
```

y=1
while y==1:

```
if Minutes in range (4,61):
    TimeMinute (Minutes) #(Minutes needs to be multiplied by 60 to make it into minutes) Minutes is currently in the unit of seconds
    y=0
else:
    Minutes=int(input ("Error. You need to enter a number between 5 and 60.\nHow long do you want the interval between each stretch to be?\nIndicate a number in minutes between 5 and 60\nAfter the minutes specified, a window with suggested stretches will appear\n-->  "))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first get the user input, then try to parse it as integer, if it fails (raises `ValueError`) then print an error message, and if it's a valid integer then check the range and do whatever you want.

```
value = input('Enter minutes :')
try:
    value = int(value)
    if 4 < value < 61:
       # Do your stuff
    else:
       print('Error value must be in range: 5-60')
except ValueError:
   print('The value you entered is not a valid integer value')
```

Comment: I was wondering what the '10' means in the third line of code after value. Will this handle text input (letters instead of numbers). I want to prevent input of anything other than integers, will this solve that?

Comment: The 10 means: convert the integers assuming they are in base 10. You can also convert hexadecimal, octal, binary or any other base strings... It's actually unnecessary since the default base is 10. I'll fix the answer. This will prevent Inputing anything else than an integer between 4 and 61.